# Apply :hover to all equal classes

Tags: html, css

I have multiple divs with the same class 'color-hover' and I'd like that the color of ALL divs change when ONE div hover.

I've coded the following but only the color of the hovered changes:

```
.color-hover {
 color: red;
}

.color-hover:hover {
 color: blue
}
```

also tried

```
.color-hover {
 color: red;
}

.color-hover:hover .color-hover {
 color: blue
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: You can't do that with CSS. You need Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to put `:hover` on the parent, not `.color-hover` itself.

But all the `.color-hover` need to be in the same container, *also it triggers while hovering the empty area of the parent*

> #### Fix
>
> As 04FS mentioned, this can be fixed by adding `pointer-events: none` to the parent and revert it in its children.

```css
.container {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.color-hover {
  color: red;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.container:hover > .color-hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="color-hover">Lorum ipsum</span>
  <span class="color-hover">Lorum ipsum</span>
  <span class="color-hover">Lorum ipsum</span>
  <span class="color-hover">Lorum ipsum</span>
  <span class="color-hover">Lorum ipsum</span>
  <span class="color-hover">Lorum ipsum</span>
  <span class="color-hover">Lorum ipsum</span>
</div>
```

---

In the future when CSS4 is out, you can achieve that by [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo class

```css
*:has(> .color-hover:hover) .color-hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: FYI: _“also it also triggers while hovering the empty area of the parent.”_ – that can be fixed by applying either `visbility:hidden` or `pointer-events:none` for the parent, and reversing it again for the children.

Comment: @04FS I didn't even know you can do that, thanks for pointing out. Edited the answer.